# how to do obfuscation of source compiled by team city

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, teamcity, obfuscation

I have set up team city to compile source code, on every check-in. now i want to do obfuscation using [Confuser](https://confuser.codeplex.com/).how to trigger it automatically after every compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit old now, however I found out the solution and may be useful for someone like me  :
Step1 :write a obfuscaticate.crproj file to obfuscaticate your dlls.
    sample for 4 dlls:

Step 2:add a build step in team city to execute the bat file(obfuscaticate.crproj) create in step 1.
Make sure you have your crproj file, dlls to obfuscaticate and Confuser dlls like :Confuser.Core.dll etc. in the same folder Dependancy(here in Image)[image]